# Find last Friday’s Date in Perl 6?

Tags: date, sequence, raku

I want to generate a sequence that ends last Friday from Monday to Thursday, and the Friday of the previous week if the sequence starts on Saturday and Sunday. That is, assuming that today is `2018-05-09`, then last Friday is `2018-05-04`,
If today is `2018-05-12`, then last Friday is **also** `2018-05-04`. So I write:

```
(Date.today, *.earlier(:1day) ... ( *.day-of-week==5 && *.week[1]+1==Date.today.week[1] )).tail # Output: 2018-05-06
```

But the result is `2018-05-06` instead of `2018-05-04`.

Then I used a [Junction](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction):

```
(Date.today, *.earlier(:1day) ... all( *.day-of-week==5,  *.week[1]+1==Date.today.week[1] )).tail # Output: 2018-05-04
```

Why `&&` in the first situation is wrong? The [...](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#index-entry-..._operators) operator says that:

> The right-hand side will have an endpoint, which can be Inf or * for "infinite" lists (whose elements are only produced on demand), an expression which will end the sequence when True, or other elements such as Junctions.

What's wrong with the `&&` operator?

Comment: The first sequence issues an error about useless use in ... in sink context. The second has the same problem. I don't think anything is wrong with the && per se.

Comment: I think that in the first sequence, "tail" is affecting just the sequence terminator. In the second case, it's well placed, but in fact what is closing the sequence is the `*.day-of-week==5` condition, which is the same I've used below.

Comment: sorry, I've add the parentheses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your ending condition

```perl6
*.day-of-week==5 && *.week[1]+1==Date.today.week[1]
```

That is two WhateverCode lambdas that each take 1 argument.

```perl6
*.day-of-week==5
```

```perl6
*.week[1]+1==Date.today.week[1]
```

Since a code object is a true value, the `&&` operator moves onto the second one. So the sequence stops when it reaches sunday of the previous week.

Even if the code was a single lambda it wouldn't work like you expect as it would be a lambda that takes two arguments.

The right way to do this check is to use some sort of block.

```perl6
{.day-of-week==5 && .week-number+1 == Date.today.week-number}
```

It might be a good idea to wrap it in a subroutine so that you can test it.

```perl6
sub last-friday ( Date:D $date ) {
  # cache it so that it doesn't have to be looked up on each iteration
  my $week-number = $date.week-number - 1;

  (
    $date,
    *.earlier( :1day )

    ...

    {
          .day-of-week == 5
      &&
          .week-number == $week-number
    }
  ).tail
}

say last-friday Date.new: :year(2018), :month( 5), :day( 9); # 2018-05-04
say last-friday Date.new: :year(2018), :month( 5), :day(12); # 2018-05-04

say Date.today.&last-friday; # 2018-05-04
```

---

You could also just calculate the proper date.

```perl6
sub last-friday ( Date:D $date ) {
  $date.earlier:
    days => (
      $date.day-of-week # reset to previous sunday
      + 2               # go two days earlier to get friday
    )
}

say last-friday Date.new: :year(2018), :month( 5), :day( 9); # 2018-05-04
say last-friday Date.new: :year(2018), :month( 5), :day(12); # 2018-05-04

say Date.today.&last-friday; # 2018-05-04
```

Comment: I don't think `*.day-of-week==5 && *.week[1]+1==Date.today.week[1]` is  a `WhateverCode` lambda that takes **2** arguments. In fact, it takes only 1 arguments. For example: `my $d = * > 12 && * %% 5;  say $d.arity` will gives **1**. It equals to `my $f = -> $a { $a > 12 && $a %% 5}` , if you pass 2 arguments, it will throw a error `Too many positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 2`.

Comment: @chenyf You are right, it is two WhateverCode lambdas.

Comment: @chenyf I was wondering why it didn't fail the first check, and why it wasn't 
landing on Saturday instead of Sunday. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This sequence will go from today to last Friday:

```
say Date.today, *.earlier(:1day) ...  *.day-of-week==5
# OUTPUT: «(2018-05-09 2018-05-08 2018-05-07 2018-05-06 2018-05-05 2018-05-04)␤»
```

Also

```
say Date.new("2018-05-11"), *.earlier(:1day) ...  *.day-of-week==5;
# OUTPUT: «(2018-05-11)␤»
```

The [last argument of the ... operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_...) is the sequence terminator, or a condition it must meet. If the sequence must end on Friday, the simplest condition is that one above.

Comment: In my opinion, **last week** is the previons week base on this week.  I dont't want Friday in **this week** (2018,19), but Friday in **last week**  or  **previous week** (2018, 18).  Sorry for my english :)

Comment: @chenyf so you mean that if it's Saturday or Sunday, you don't want that Friday, but the previous one...

Comment: yes, `if Date.today == '2018-05-12' | '2018-05-13'` , the output should be  `2018-05-04` instead of `2018-05-11`(this Friday). so I used `week` method to get the week number.

Comment: It might be easier to solve that outside the sequence... But I will give it a try.