# Filtering elements matching two regexes in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Something is going on here that I don't quite understand.

```perl6
> my @arr = <ac bc abc>
> @arr.grep: (( * ~~ /a/ ) && ( * ~~ /b/ ))
(bc abc)
```

But

```perl6
> @arr.grep(* ~~ /a/).grep(* ~~ /b/)
(abc)
```

What's the reason?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272983/whateverstar-whateverstar-in-perl-6

Comment: @raiph Thanks! Not sure that I understood much in the answers, so my easiest solution would be: `@a.grep: { /a/ && /b/ }`

Comment: @raiph And strangely even a `Juncture` works: `@a.grep:  /a/&/b/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've come up with perfectly cromulent solutions.

Another would be:

```
my @arr = <ac bc abc>
@arr.grep: { $_ ~~ /a/ && $_ ~~ /b/ }
(abc)
```

The rest of this answer just explains the problem. The problem in this question is a more complicated version of the problem covered at [WhateverStar `&&` WhateverStar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272983/whateverstar-whateverstar-in-perl-6).

---

The logical ops don't execute their arguments if they're code.

So `{ $_ ~~ /a/ } && { $_ ~~ /b/ }` returns `{ $_ ~~ /b/ }`.

Or `* ~~ /a/ && * ~~ /b/` returns `* ~~ /b/`.

At the same time, `grep` *does* execute its matcher if it's code or if it's a regex, so these are all the same:

```
foo.grep: { $_ ~~ /.../ }
foo.grep:    * ~~ /.../;
foo.grep:         /.../;
```

## The magic of `Junction`s

Your `Junction` solution seems natural. I'd love it if someone could explain what I'm missing in the following. While I *expected* it to work, it's bending my head to figure out how it actually works but I think it's something like (but not quite):

- `foo & bar` becomes a `Junction` of `foo` *and* `bar`.
- An attempt is made to invoke `grep` with a `Junction` as an argument.
- Because `Junction` is outside the normal `Any` value hierarchy, most routines don't have a matching signature. `grep` doesn't.
- When you invoke a routine and there is no corresponding signature then the initial dispatch fails and we hit a dispatch fallback handler. [This](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/38d046fafb42aab3391f49cd97cef6150298e397/src/Perl6/Metamodel/ClassHOW.nqp#L248) may be the method one.
- If the dispatch fallback handler sees there are `Junction` arguments then it extracts the individual values in the `Junction` and fires up logically parallel "threads" (currently never *actual* threads, but the compiler is allowed to make them real threads if it thinks that is a good idea) corresponding to those values. Thus it invokes `grep` twice per element of the invocant and outputs the results back into a new `Junction` of the same type as the incoming `Junction`.
- In boolean context, a `Junction` collapses to a single result.
- (If a `Junction` is in an overall boolean context then it can (parallel) short-circuits based on results. If it's an `any` and *any* result comes in `True` then it can cancel the rest -- or not do them in the first place if it's actually doing things sequentially, as is currently always the case. If it's an `all` and any result comes in `False` it can cancel the rest. Etc.)