# Where is contains( Junction) defined?

Tags: raku, perl6-junction

This code works:

```
(3,6...66).contains( 9|21 ).say  # OUTPUT: «any(True, True)␤»
```

And returns a [`Junction`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction). It's also [tested](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/7dc829e0fbd87d271e5ad3feb2ce3b01ab79f983/S32-list/classify.t), but [not documented](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/contains).
The problem is I can't find its implementation anywhere. The [Str code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Str.pm6#L182-L203), which is also called from Cool, never returns a Junction (it does not take a Junction, either). There are no other [methods `contain`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=%22method+contains%22&unscoped_q=%22method+contains%22) in source.
Since it's autothreaded, it's probably specially defined somewhere. I have no idea where, though. Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR** Junction autothreading is handled by a single central mechanism. I have a go at explaining it below.

(The body of your question starts with you falling into a trap, one I think you documented a year or two back. It seems pretty irrelevant to what you're really asking but I cover that too.)

## How junctions get handled

> Where is contains( Junction) defined? ... The problem is I can't find [the Junctional] implementation anywhere. ... Since it's autothreaded, it's probably specially defined somewhere.

Yes. There's a generic mechanism that automatically applies autothreading to *all* P6 routines (methods, operators etc.) that don't have signatures that explicitly control what happens with `Junction` arguments.

Only a tiny handful of built in routines have these explicit `Junction` handling signatures -- `print` is perhaps the most notable. The same is true of user defined routines.

`.contains` does *not* have any special handling. So it is handled automatically by the generic mechanism.

Perhaps the section **The magic of `Junctions`** of [my answer to an earlier SO **Filtering elements matching two regexes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581555/1077672) will be helpful as a high level description of the low level details that follow below. Just substitute your `9|21` for the `foo & bar` in that SO, and your `.contains` for the `grep`, and it hopefully makes sense.

## Spelunking the code

I'll focus on methods. Other routines are handled in a similar fashion.

[`method AUTOTHREAD`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1611795d524fea7e2e623e4779813f3f59dee363/src/core/Junction.pm6#L310-L380) does the work for full P6 methods.

This is setup in [this code that sets up handling for both nqp and full P6 code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1611795d524fea7e2e623e4779813f3f59dee363/src/core/Junction.pm6#L542-L549).

The above linked P6 setup code in turn calls [setup_junction_fallback](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7bd3b3a0a8a3c1faaef602d2d3fe1e619e4ef640/src/Perl6/Metamodel/ClassHOW.nqp#L266-L270).

When a method call occurs in a user's program, it involves calling [`find_method`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1ff9b14e8903d77f066f7c2673ea59d6ad7f4aa6/src/Perl6/Metamodel/MROBasedMethodDispatch.nqp#L4-L25) (modulo cache hits as explained in the comment above that code; note that the use of the word "fallback" in that comment is about a cache miss -- which is technically unrelated to the other fallback mechanisms evident in this code we're spelunking thru).

The [bit of code near the end of this `find_method`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/1ff9b14e8903d77f066f7c2673ea59d6ad7f4aa6/src/Perl6/Metamodel/MROBasedMethodDispatch.nqp#L22-L25) handles (non-cache-miss) fallbacks.

Which arrives at [`find_method_fallback`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/38d046fafb42aab3391f49cd97cef6150298e397/src/Perl6/Metamodel/ClassHOW.nqp#L247-L266) which starts off with the actual junction handling stuff.

## A trap

> This code works:

```
(3,6...66).contains( 9|21 ).say  # OUTPUT: «any(True, True)␤»
```

It "works" to the degree this does too:

```
(3,6...66).contains( 2 | '9 1' ).say  # OUTPUT: «any(True, True)␤»
```

See [Lists become strings, so beware `.contains()`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#Lists_become_strings,_so_beware_.contains%28%29) and/or discussion of the underlying issues such as [pmichaud's comment](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/992#issuecomment-313412447).

Routines like `print`, `put`, infix `~`, and `.contains` are *string* routines. That means they coerce their arguments to `Str`. By default the `.Str` coercion of a listy value is its elements separated by spaces:

```
put 3,6...18;                    # 3 6 9 12 15 18
put (3,6...18).contains: '9 1';  # True
```

> It's also tested

Presumably you mean the two tests with a `*.contains` argument passed to `classify`:

```
my $m := @l.classify: *.contains: any 'a'..'f';
my $s := classify *.contains( any 'a'..'f'), @l;
```

Routines like `classify` are *list* routines. While some list routines do a single operation on their list argument/invocant, eg `push`, most of them, including `classify`, iterate over their list doing something with/to *each element* within the list.

Given a sequence invocant/argument, `classify` will iterate it and pass each element to the test, in this case a `*.contains`.

The latter will then coerce *individual elements* to `Str`. This is a fundamental difference compared to your example which coerces a sequence to `Str` in one go.

Comment: We should probably document more explicitly that Junction magic. That's probably the reason why Junctions are not in Any. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi JJ. I've just inverted the focus of my answer to the junction mechanism. It's just a first quick cut. I've got to do a bunch of other stuff for most of today and tomorrow, but if you give me a few days I hope to more clearly understand the high level details of the code I spelunked and update this answer. That might be helpful towards documenting the mechanism. I should note that I consider the junction mechanism to be a well designed -- it's not "magic" in the negative sense folk often mean in a technical context. So I'll be eliminating use of that word. :)

Comment: you've probably realized this opens a whole new Pandora box of undocumented stuff...

Comment: I just got back online. I haven't had time to realize anything. :) The doc says "Autothreading happens when a junction is bound to a parameter ... that doesn't accept values of type `Junction`. Instead of producing an error, the signature binding is repeated for each value of the junction." To me that's essentially it. The rest is mostly unpacking this mechanism's simplicity, generality, and power -- I currently see the doc situation more like the lack of a menu in a Forrest Gumpian box of chocolates than a Pandora's box. :)

Comment: that document says that. But if all routines, or most, have a fallback autothreading option for Junctions, well, it should be at least noted.

Comment: For me, it was one of those "Aha Erlebnisse" some year ago.  It is visible through `dd Junction.^mro; # (Junction, Mu)`.  The fact that a `Junction` is **not** an `Any`, allows autothreading to work.  This is why we need to be careful with creating candidates that have `Mu` types in their signature: either they will have to handle `Junction` themselves, or they have to rely on `Junction`s being handled by calls that these candidates make.  If anything needs to be documented, I think it is this fact, rather than documenting `Junction` behaviour everywhere.